# Tensorflow text classification sample why need from_logits=True?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I’m running a basic text classification sample from Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification).

One thing I don’t understand is that why we need to use `from_logits=True` with `BinaryCrossentropy` loss? When I tried to remove it and add `activation="sigmoid"` to the last `Dense` layer then `binary_accuracy` does not move at all when training.

**Changed code:**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")]) # <-- Add activation = sigmoid here

model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), # <-- Remove from_logits=True here
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0))

epochs = 10
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

**Training outputs:**

```
    Epoch 1/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 4s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6635 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.6149 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 2/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5492 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.4990 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 3/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4453 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.4208 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 4/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3792 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.3741 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 5/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3360 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.3454 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 6/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3054 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.3262 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 7/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2813 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.3126 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 8/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2616 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.3033 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 9/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2456 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.2967 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
    Epoch 10/10
    625/625 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2306 - binary_accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 0.2920 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5076
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the model is being trained as normal, but the calculation method to show you how the model is being trained is wrong at the moment.

I think `threshold` in `BinaryAccuracy` is accfecting the result of the metrics. For example, because you've changed your input to the loss function as one after the `sigmoid`, the values would range between `0` and `1`, but your `BinaryAccuracy` `threshold` is now `0.0`, which should be `0.5`.

**Try change that value to `0.5`**, if you want to modify the model archtecture as you want.

Comment: To add some more explanation, if `from_logit=True` the value to the loss function would range any real number, and `0.0` would be the boundary to distinguish values that would be below `0.5` -> eventually marked as **negative**, above `0.5` -> eventually marked as **positive**, if they are going to go through sigmoid function at last.